# could anyone tell me what's wrong with my mail form although data is posted correctly but email is not sending. Why?

Tags: php, email

to submit a form using email functionality:

```
$to = "ayush@***.com"; 
$from = $_REQUEST['email']; 
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
$message = $_REQUEST['message'];

$subject = "Form submission";

$message = $name . " " . $phone . " " .$message. " wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $_REQUEST['message'];

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=isoo-8859-1\r\n";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
```

i am not able to send email

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

header('Location: thank-you.php');
```

Comment: mail() function is not always sufficient to sending mail in all hosting providers. Try SMTP or PHPMailer.

Comment: And use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`. Request contains GET, POST and COOKIE, so you won't be sure that the data really comes from the post.

Answer (score 2):

Your last header is broken.

```
$headers = "From:" . $from;
```

It requires the dot (concatenate) for it also.

```
$headers .= "From:" . $from;
```

Mail is rejected since there is no valid `From` and is caused by it being broken.